# looking for examples/samples using Spark aggregate and group by in Cassandra

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, cassandra-2.1

I want to run the following query using Spark Python (pull data from Cassandra) similar to Oracle SQL:

```
select name, value, count(*) from table_name order by name, value 
group by name....
```

any examples/samples will help, thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using Scala

```
val results = sqlContext.sql(
    "select name, value, count(*) from table group by name, value"
)
```